Higgs VEV and the Minkowski metric
The empty spacetime is described by the Minkowski metric. However, does the Higgs VEV has any effect on the Minkowski metric? If so, how?

Why would it have any effect?

Hi @Prahar, given that Higgs VEV might contribute to the energy of the vacuum, wouldn't be possible that it can change the metric?
